# is it possible to reload the same page on clicking browsers back button?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page called index_php where user can log in and moves to next page .where the next page contains log out button.if i click log out button . it will move to logout_php where it will destroy session and moves to index_php. so on click browsers back button then the  page should reload .

Comment: You have to check whether the user is logged in on every page that requires authentication and redirect if necessary.

Comment: Be specific about what you want.. what you want can be done by checking the session on index.php and sending the user back to the 'logged in' page

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to parse, but I think you're looking for the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.